# Index for self-joining query with spatial data

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to speed up a query using an index or indexes, but what ever I try, the indexes instead slows down the query.

```
                   Table "public.mergegroups"
   Column    |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 groupid     | bigint           |           | not null | 
 mergevalue  | text             |           | not null | 
 category    | text             |           |          | 
 geom        | geometry         |           |          | 
 geom_length | double precision |           |          |
```

And the query:

```
explain analyze select
       g1.groupid as gid1,
       g2.groupid as gid2
    from mergegroups g1, mergegroups g2
    where
       g1.mergevalue = g2.mergevalue and
       g1.category = g2.category and
       g1.groupid < g2.groupid and
       ST_DWithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, g1.geom_length / 2) and
       ST_DWithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, g2.geom_length / 2)
    limit 5000000;
```

Query plan without any indexes on mergegroups:

```
 Limit  (cost=35150.87..117447204.92 rows=114 width=16) (actual time=474.061..18547.382 rows=604888 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=35150.87..117447204.92 rows=114 width=16) (actual time=316.622..18357.044 rows=604888 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 3
         Workers Launched: 3
         ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=34150.87..117446193.52 rows=37 width=16) (actual time=286.893..18287.403 rows=151222 loops=4)
               Hash Cond: ((g1.mergevalue = g2.mergevalue) AND (g1.category = g2.category))
               Join Filter: ((g1.groupid < g2.groupid) AND st_dwithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, (g1.geom_length / '2'::double precision)) AND st_dwithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, (g2.geom_length / '2'::double precision)))
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 31911182
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on mergegroups g1  (cost=0.00..29891.55 rows=283955 width=217) (actual time=0.003..27.721 rows=220065 loops=4)
               ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=29891.55..29891.55 rows=283955 width=217) (actual time=285.379..285.379 rows=220065 loops=4)
                     Buckets: 1048576  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 226528kB
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on mergegroups g2  (cost=0.00..29891.55 rows=283955 width=217) (actual time=0.008..18.010 rows=220065 loops=4)
 Planning Time: 3.254 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 69
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 7.039 ms, Inlining 182.027 ms, Optimization 430.972 ms, Emission 254.927 ms, Total 874.966 ms
 Execution Time: 18568.124 ms
```

Query plan with `create index on mergegroups (mergevalue, category, groupid);`

```
 Limit  (cost=1000.42..14371481.40 rows=114 width=16) (actual time=86.235..20398.784 rows=604888 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=1000.42..14371481.40 rows=114 width=16) (actual time=0.943..20279.928 rows=604888 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 3
         Workers Launched: 3
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..14370470.00 rows=37 width=16) (actual time=105.586..20242.939 rows=151222 loops=4)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on mergegroups g1  (cost=0.00..29891.55 rows=283955 width=217) (actual time=0.007..19.058 rows=220065 loops=4)
               ->  Index Scan using mergegroups_mergevalue_category_groupid_idx on mergegroups g2  (cost=0.42..50.49 rows=1 width=217) (actual time=0.022..0.091 rows=1 loops=880260)
                     Index Cond: ((mergevalue = g1.mergevalue) AND (category = g1.category) AND (groupid > g1.groupid))
                     Filter: (st_dwithin(g1.geom, geom, (g1.geom_length / '2'::double precision)) AND st_dwithin(g1.geom, geom, (geom_length / '2'::double precision)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 72
 Planning Time: 3.688 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 41
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 4.604 ms, Inlining 190.732 ms, Optimization 197.432 ms, Emission 117.553 ms, Total 510.322 ms
 Execution Time: 20419.549 ms
```

Query plan with `create index on mergegroups using gist (mergevalue, category, groupid, geom);` (this index only). (This requires `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;`)

```
 Limit  (cost=1000.54..14407331.20 rows=114 width=16) (actual time=98.578..20937.519 rows=604888 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=1000.54..14407331.20 rows=114 width=16) (actual time=3.860..20807.147 rows=604888 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 3
         Workers Launched: 3
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.54..14406319.80 rows=37 width=16) (actual time=120.259..20764.514 rows=151222 loops=4)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on mergegroups g1  (cost=0.00..29891.55 rows=283955 width=217) (actual time=0.007..30.567 rows=220065 loops=4)
               ->  Index Scan using mergegroups_mergevalue_category_groupid_geom_idx on mergegroups g2  (cost=0.54..50.62 rows=1 width=217) (actual time=0.083..0.092 rows=1 loops=880260)
                     Index Cond: ((mergevalue = g1.mergevalue) AND (category = g1.category) AND (groupid > g1.groupid) AND (geom && st_expand(g1.geom, (g1.geom_length / '2'::double precision))))
                     Filter: (st_dwithin(g1.geom, geom, (g1.geom_length / '2'::double precision)) AND st_dwithin(g1.geom, geom, (geom_length / '2'::double precision)))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 0
 Planning Time: 3.035 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 45
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 4.852 ms, Inlining 198.911 ms, Optimization 226.550 ms, Emission 143.788 ms, Total 574.101 ms
 Execution Time: 20959.232 ms
```

As you can see, lowest execution time when no index at all!

Comment: Hash joins are awesome.  Sometimes indexes are not better.  Since they don't help here, don't build them.  But they also don't hurt much, so maybe build one anyway if it helps something else.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, made me realize I had to read up on postgres join strategies. It seems, for moderate size tables the hash join is really fast. For larger tables, the composite index strategy (last example) is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
ST_DWithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, g1.geom_length / 2) and
ST_DWithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, g2.geom_length / 2)
```

This is the bottleneck of the query.

First, since `st_dwithin` is an expansive function, you can reduce it to one call:

```
ST_DWithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, least(g1.geom_length,g2.geom_length) / 2)
```

But since the distance is dynamic, a geometry index won't be used. To speed up the query, you will want to to pre-filter the rows with the largest possible distance (which you could compute in a CTE first), using a cheap `&&` bounding box operation. You would need a regular spatial index too.

```
CREATE INDEX ON mergegroups USING gist (geom);

explain analyze select
       g1.groupid as gid1,
       g2.groupid as gid2
    from mergegroups g1, mergegroups g2
    where
       g1.mergevalue = g2.mergevalue and
       g1.category = g2.category and
       g1.groupid < g2.groupid and
        g1.geom && ST_Expand(g2.geom, 1000) AND -- <*************
       ST_DWithin(g1.geom, g2.geom, least(g1.geom_length,g2.geom_length) / 2)
    limit 5000000;
```